# Ionic: Links not opening in system browser?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, ionic-framework

I'm trying to open links in the device's system browser but it isn't working. I'm getting my data/links from a json file on a http.get request.

The code i'm using is from here http://intown.biz/2014/03/30/cordova-ionic-links-in-browser/

My code:

HTML:

```
 <p style="text-align:left"> <span ng-bind-html="item.content | externalLinks"></span></p>
```

Javascript:

Filter:

```
.filter('externalLinks', function() {
   return function(text) {
     return String(text).replace(/href=/gm, "class=\"ex-link\" href=");
   }
 });
```

Js:

```
    .controller('announcementCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

       $timeout(function () {
       $('.ex-link').click(function () {
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system', 'location=yes');
         return false;
       })
    })
  });
```

I'm not receiving any errors it just isn't working. I

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(encodeURI(url))` or just `console.log(url)` ?

Comment: How do you open console log in ionic?

Comment: [Check out the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html)